# Can you use Monistat on a dogs paw for yeast infection?

Tags: dogs, health, medicines, infections

My mom's dog, an 8 years old Coton de Tuléar named Henri was seen by an "in and out" vet, a shot clinic basically. When the vet asked whether she has any health concerns besides shots, she replied by letting him know he chewed on his feet, his back feet were red in color and she'd suspected a grass allergy. The vet gave her a spray (Allercain with Bittran) for topical allergies and a bitter taste to eliminate chewing, asked her about her food (already feeding a limited ingredient diet- so no change necessary), suggested adding salmon oil to his food daily and giving him a half of a Zyrtec pill daily, hidden in a pill pocket or treat.

He's been on this recommended combination for a month with no change, and she said it actually appears worse. His foot is now balding in some places, still red, inflamed and chewing has not stopped. It's especially darker red in between his toes, which suggests to me he has yeast on his feet.

I have experience with AND know you can use Monistat on yeast infections in dogs' ears BUT dogs can't chew on their ears. Maybe that's why it's safe?

Does anyone know if it is safe to put Monistat on a place that may end up being licked? There's a high probability he will continue chewing until it clears up. If he can't be treated with Monistat or an athlete foot cream, she knows he will have to return to the vet (non-clinic), but was hoping to try something more affordable, without being charged for "extras". She also mentioned using lemon juice, that it's a natural antifungal and would be sour in taste to keep him from chewing, but I fear it would sting pretty bad any areas he's chewed raw.

If anyone has experience with this, stories of experience included with answers are appreciated.

If it helps, I'll have her send me pics of his feet to share with the Pets Community. Thanks in advance!

I should also add the vet did not perform a physical examination and my mom said he didn't thoroughly examine the dog's foot (guess it wasn't part of the package - not sure), and he has no fleas, no hair loss nor redness anywhere except just back feet and one is worse than the other.

Comment: I actually am trying this for the first time today. I did buy an e- collar because everything I read about it said to. I have to say has only been a couple of hours. He seems to be relieved. sleeping finally without waking up to scratch. haven’t shaken his head either. I am extremely relieved and can’t wait to see him irritant free!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Miconazole (active ingredient of Monistat) is a commonly used topical antifungal. It is safe to apply to your dog's paws in small amount. Carefully clean and dry the paws before applying a small amount of Monistat in between the toes.

Obviously it is not ideal if he licks it right off – the medication will not have time to work, and while he is unlikely to ingest enough to cause toxicity there is always a small risk. Toxicity is more of a concern if a dog chews the whole tube, but while I have seen dogs chew many things a tube of Monistat is not – yet – one of them. If he did ingest a small amount I suspect the worst he would have is an upset stomach, but it is difficult to say for certain.

I would recommend the dog wear an e-collar for the time being, to prevent further damage to the paws as well as to prevent ingestion of any topical treatment.

He might be a dog who would benefit from wearing boots in the short term, but not while his feet have yeast infections.

I do recommend taking him to a vet (who will, please, examine the feet) since while Monistat might provide some relief it is just going to mask the underlying problem.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!!! i will send her the link so she can  read the answer and decide what to do next. My mom has little socks she made for him with a rigged drawstring at the ankle, bc he pulls them off. Do you think she should put these on until the creme dries, OR do you think that will just harbor a more dark and moist place for yeast to thrive? Tgis may be an option until she gets to the vet AND gets an e-collar, most likely not until Friday or Saturday

Comment: @ChristyB I would say it's fine to wear the socks in the short term, but check the feet frequently (multiple times per day) to make sure it's not creating a warm wet environment for yeast and bacteria to thrive.

Comment: My dog gets yeast infections on her paws and frequently licks them as well. This was confirmed by a vet who specializes in dermatology. Based on his advice, I control it with chlorhexidine pads each morning during allergy season (basically all but winter). I use these pads: https://www.amazon.com/Sogeval-Douxo-Count-Chlorhexidine-Pads/dp/B00G3D8JL0/ref=sr_1_1?s=pet-supplies&ie=UTF8&qid=1507135933&sr=1-1&keywords=duoxo+chlorhexidine+pads

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely the best thing I have ever found it works like a miracle my York’s mix has severe yeast problems it cleared up so fast I’m such a believer i bought the generic version miconazole 7 at Walmart I put it between her toes and her ears arm pits every where and used an antibacterial shampoo it took about a week and she’s completely healed up please everybody that has a yeast problem in dogs use it

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange Pets! Please take some time to edit your post and add some punctuation marks. As it is, your answer is hard to understand because it lacks any and all punctuation.